# docker fails to open container in dev mode

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

im Starting a Dev-Mode Container in docker. the documentation says this line

```
docker run -dp 3000:3000 -w /app -v $PWD:/app node:10-alpine sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev"
```

however this might be for linux im on windows. the rest of the internet are suggesting this

```
docker run -dp 3000:3000 -w /app -v "%cd%:/app" node:10-alpine sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev"
```

this does not return any sort of error just a complicated load of letters and numbers (probably some kind of object or w/e its in the screenshot)

however docker ps suggests nothing is running, no containers are open. also when i open up docker desktop app i can see each time i run the line above i do create a new container it just dies straight away.
[image]
im not doing anything special, why does that container crash on opening? i just want it to run normal.

what further info would be useful?

######################################
edit

following the advice of printing the logs i see that my app cannot find a file.
however this leaves me more confused because as the screenshot shows, docker is looking in the right place and the files really are there.

[image]

Comment: You can use `docker logs` to check why the containers stopped

Comment: Are you using Powershell? Do you actually have your app in the current directory?

Comment: 1 second more evidence to come

Comment: If the `package.json` was not found, it seems that the volume mounting was performed incorrectly.
Apart from this, SO guides that error logs that can be expressed in text such as docker logs in your explanation are written in text format rather than images. It looks like it needs to be rewritten by following the guide below. [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `package.json` appears to be in `C:\Users\tgmjack\app`. Not `C:\Users\tgmjack`.
Can you change `"%cd%:/app"` to `"%cd%/app:/app"`?

Answer (score 0):

The folder mounted is **C:\Users\tgmjack** and it should be **C:\Users\tgmjack\app** because that is the folder containing the **package.json** file.

So you should run `docker run -dp 3000:3000 -w /app -v "%cd%:/app" node:10-alpine sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev"` from the **C:\Users\tgmjack\app** folder.